# Smoother transition in movement?

Tags: c#, sfml

I am back with another question. I am still new to SFML so this one seemed a bit tough. I have tried using while loops and such but to no avail.

The game I am doing at the moment is a car going back and forth on the X axis and then I guess will be able to pick up points and stuff or simply just avoid objects coming towards the car until it eventually dies.

How do I make the movement smoother? Currently the car will move 8 units first, before moving 8 units in the desired direction until I let go of the button. It's the same when I do it the other way. I would like it to just instantly move and keep moving when I press either key.

```
    static void OnKeyPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Vector2f newPos = new Vector2f(0, car.Position.Y);
        KeyEventArgs ke = (KeyEventArgs)e;
        if (ke.Code.Equals(Keyboard.Key.A))
        {
            if (car.Position.X != 0)
            {
                newPos.X = car.Position.X - 8;
                car.Position = newPos;
            }
            else if (car.Position.X < 0)
            {
                newPos.X = 0;
                car.Position = newPos;
            }
            else if(car.Position.X == 0)
            {
                // Do nothing
            }
        }
        else if (ke.Code.Equals(Keyboard.Key.D))
        {
            if (car.Position.X != window.Size.X - 32)
            {
                newPos.X = car.Position.X + 8;
                car.Position = newPos;
            }
            else if (car.Position.X > window.Size.X)
            {
                newPos.X = window.Size.X;
                car.Position = newPos;
            }
            else if (car.Position.X == window.Size.X)
            {
                // Do nothing
            }
        }
    }
```

And the entire thing for reference:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SFML.Audio;
using SFML.Graphics;
using SFML.Window;

namespace SFMLCarGame
{
    class Program
    {
        private static RenderWindow window;
        private static Sprite car;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            window = new RenderWindow(new VideoMode(256,512), "Car Game");
            window.Closed += new EventHandler(OnClose);
            window.KeyPressed += new EventHandler<KeyEventArgs>(OnKeyPressed);

            Sprite bg = new Sprite(new Texture("road.png"));
            car = new Sprite(new Texture("car.png"));
            car.Position = new Vector2f(window.Size.X / 2, window.Size.Y - 96);
            while (window.IsOpen())
            {
                window.DispatchEvents();

                window.Clear();

                window.Draw(bg);
                window.Draw(car);

                window.Display();
            }
        }

        static void OnClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RenderWindow window = (RenderWindow)sender;
            window.Close();
        }

        static void OnKeyPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Vector2f newPos = new Vector2f(0, car.Position.Y);
            KeyEventArgs ke = (KeyEventArgs)e;
            if (ke.Code.Equals(Keyboard.Key.A))
            {
                if (car.Position.X != 0)
                {
                    newPos.X = car.Position.X - 8;
                    car.Position = newPos;
                }
                else if (car.Position.X < 0)
                {
                    newPos.X = 0;
                    car.Position = newPos;
                }
                else if(car.Position.X == 0)
                {
                    // Do nothing
                }
            }
            else if (ke.Code.Equals(Keyboard.Key.D))
            {
                if (car.Position.X != window.Size.X - 32)
                {
                    newPos.X = car.Position.X + 8;
                    car.Position = newPos;
                }
                else if (car.Position.X > window.Size.X)
                {
                    newPos.X = window.Size.X;
                    car.Position = newPos;
                }
                else if (car.Position.X == window.Size.X)
                {
                    // Do nothing
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly do you want? You want smoother transitions but then you said you want instant movement?

Comment: When you currently use any of the two movement keys, you first see the car do like an 8 unit skip before starting to move in one motion, rather than just moving in one motion from the get-go. What would you call that if I had to edit the question?

Comment: Well it looks like you're updating the car position from the event listeners. This means the skipping is related to the delays between keyboard repeats. Hold down any key while typing text and you'll see. If you want proper animation, you need a proper loop setup. I can explain it further if you like or you can hunt around for game design tutorials.

Comment: I would love to have it explained please! You can include it as an answer if you wish, and I can accept that :)

Comment: I'll write up an answer in a little while unless someone else does first.

Comment: Thanks Nikki! That would be a great help :3

Comment: Apologies Vipar, it looks like I'll be tied up for the rest of the day. I don't have any C# code examples handy to give you. There's a few in other languages but that probably doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to read this [short tutorial](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/window-inputs.php) from the SFML's website.

The events are fired by the operating system, and are good for certain purposes (quit event, a key is pressed, the left mouse button is clicked) but aren't for things that need to be updated really often. Imagine that you are writing some text, and keep the 'A' key pressed. Your text will progressively grow like `aaaaaaaaaaa` but there is a little delay between the a spawns, imposed by the OS. You would get, say, 6 letters by second. This is the same with events. With a game running and displaying at 60 fps it is clear that your movement will not be smooth and barely manageable.

Hopefully SFML provides a way to check the instant state of the keyboard (and mouse and joystick). With the C# binding (I am assuming you are using the binding for 2.0 version, and if you don't then you should) you only have to check `Keyboard.isKeyPressed(yourKey)`.
Doing this in the main loop will check at each frame that the key is pressed, and not wait for an OS event that is way slower.

On a side note, if your previous questions were answered correctly please mark them so by accepting an answer.

**Edit :** I haven't SFML for .NET installed on my computer but here is what it could look like

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        window = new RenderWindow(new VideoMode(256,512), "Car Game");
        window.Closed += new EventHandler(OnClose);
        // Note this
        // window.KeyPressed += new EventHandler<KeyEventArgs>(OnKeyPressed);

        Sprite bg = new Sprite(new Texture("road.png"));
        car = new Sprite(new Texture("car.png"));
        car.Position = new Vector2f(window.Size.X / 2, window.Size.Y - 96);
        while (window.IsOpen())
        {
            window.DispatchEvents();
            CheckInputs(); // and this !

            window.Clear();

            window.Draw(bg);
            window.Draw(car);

            window.Display();
        }
    }

void CheckInputs()
{
    if(Keyboard.isKeyPressed(Keyboard.key.A))
    {
        if(car.Position.X < 0)
            car.Position.X = 0
        else if(car.Position.X > 0)
            car.Position.X -= 8; // shortcut for 'car.Position.X = car.Position.X - 8'
    }
    else if(Keyboard.isKeyPressed(Keyboard.key.D))
    {
        // etc
    }
}
```

This way your transition should be much smoother, but beware, 8 pixels might be very fast !
I really recommend you to read the tutorial I have linked, because it explains the functionning of inputs in an language-agnostic way (even if the examples are in C++).

Also, you don't need your event handler anymore so I commented it. **But** if you are checking for other keys (like escape for pause or whatever) don't delete it, just remove the part you wrote about moving the car.

Comment: I do accept answers on the questions where I get an answer. I will check into what you said tomorrow though!

Comment: OK, hope it helps you! The tutorials on the website are for C++ but you can easily translate them into C#.

Comment: I wish I could actually do C++ T_T

Comment: I edited the answer to provide you a little example based on your program.